# How do i get space between groupings in a listview through xaml (xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to achieve a space between the different groupings in a listview like my picture.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Vglbeyz]

How can I do this through xaml?

I have tried adding the some margin and padding to the GroupHeaderTemplate without any luck.

```
 <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame Margin="0,20,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="#324458" >
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="white" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Margin="0,3,0,3"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Text="LPic" />
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Margin="0,3,0,3"  Text="30. SEP" />

                    </Grid>

                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the **Frame** in another **Frame** and set the **Padding** of it

```
<ViewCell>
  <Frame Margin="0" Padding="0,20,0,0" BackgroundColor="#324458" >
    <Frame >
       <Grid >
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="40" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="white" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
           <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Margin="0,3,0,3"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Text="LPic" />
           <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Margin="0,3,0,3"  Text="30. SEP" />

        </Grid>
   </Frame>
 </Frame>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: This did the job Thanks!

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding padding to the top and bottom of the Frame e.g. Padding="0,20,0,20"? play with the values for top and bottom padding until you get your ideal result.
If that doesn't work try adding the padding to the ViewCell.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is add another RowDefinition to the grid and give it some height saw 20 and make this new RowDefinition as the first row and existing row as the second row.